# На брейк поинте работают некоторые классы(css)

Tags: html, css, html5

На расширении экрана 767 могу изменять menu_body,menu_list, но изменять li,a(menu_item,link) не дает менять цвет, font-size, выставлять паддинги и в принципе на команды не реагирует
codepen - `https://codepen.io/aleksandrsanduliak/pen/bGYBrmQ`

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Go Corona</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header__container">
                    <a href="" class="header__logo">
                        <img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                    <nav class="header__menu menu">
                        <nav id="menu" class="menu__body">
                        <ul class="menu__list">
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">HOME</a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">FEATURES</a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">SUPPORT</a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="header__button">
                        <a href="" class="button button_blue">DOWNLOAD</a>
                        <a href="#menu" class="icon-menu"><span> </span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </header>
        
        <main class="main"> main </main>
    
        <footer class="footer">footer </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    a, li{
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    body, html{
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-size: 12px;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: #616161;
    }
    
    ol, li{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .main { 
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    [class *="__container"]{
        max-width: 1087px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    
    .icon-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1087px){
        [class *="__container"]{
            max-width: 970px;
    
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 991.98px){
        .header__container{
            min-height: 88px;
        }
        [class *="__container"]{
            max-width: 750x;
        }
        .header__button{
            flex: 0 0 150px;
        }
        .menu__item{
            margin: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
        }
    
    }  
    
    @media (max-width: 767.98px){
        [class *="__container"]{
            max-width: none;
        }
        .icon-menu{
            position: relative;
            flex: 0 0 30px;
            height: 18px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
        }
        
        .icon-menu::before,
        .icon-menu::after{
            content: "";
            background-color: black;
            height: 2px;
            }
        
        .icon-menu span{
         background-color: black;
         height: 2px;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 767.98px){
     .menu__body{
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: #587eec;
         padding: 40px 15px 30px 15px;
     }
     .menu__list{
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
     }
     .menu__item{
         margin: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
     }
     .menu__item:last-child{
         margin-bottom: 0;
     }
     .menu__link{
         color: #FFF;
         font-size: 20px;
     }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 479.98px){
        .header__logo{
            flex: 0 0 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
    .header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .header__container {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 114px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .header__logo {
    z-index: 5;
    }
    
    .header__menu {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    
    .menu__list {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .menu__item {
        margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    .menu__link {
    font-family: Raleway;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }
    
    .header__button {
        flex: 0 0 252px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    
    .button {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Raleway;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FCFDFE;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        background-color: #EC5863;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
        line-height: 1.2px;
    }
    .button:hover{
        background-color:#EC5863 ;
    
    }
    .button_blue {
        background-color: #4285F4;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .button_blue:hover{
        background-color: #34f57e;  
    }
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы ваши медиа-запросы работали их нужно размещать после всего контента, в данном случае разместить после стилей для .header, .menu...

Answer (score 0):

Медиа запросы нужно писать в конце файла: Вот так:

```
.menu__link {
    color: black;
}
@media (max-width: 767.98px){
    .menu__link {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!